# how to read places.sqlite of firefox using c# application

Tags: c#, sqlite, firefox

Hi I am trying to get all history url of mozilla firefox. To do that I am accessing places.sqlite file inside %appdata%mozilla/firefox/profile/*.default folder. I am using system.data.sqlite dll in my code and tried x64 and x86 both of the solution. As I am trying to connect the database it is showing me an exception that the file is encrypted or not a database file.
To cross check this exception I've installed a dbmanager for sqlite and opened it. This is showing me all the data that I want to show. But I am not able to get the same data using c# application. Please Help me to get this thing resolved.

```
SQLiteConnection sqlite_connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

            SQLiteCommand sqlite_command = sqlite_connection.CreateCommand();

            sqlite_connection.Open();// exception occurs here
```

Comment: Have you tried to move the database file to another location? Maybe the opening of the file in that place needs more rights than the application has.

Comment: I've put that file from appdata folder to c:\\ but still same error !!!

Comment: Are you sure that the sqlite database is version 3 like you use in the connection string ?

Comment: I am not sure about this thing, I am trying to access places.sqlite file and the version that I've mentioned in query string is working with other project

Comment: I dont know which dbmanager you got, but just try to convert the places.sqlite to version 3 (the dbmanager may have an option for that)